# how can i make a get request in axios to get the info of a user by clicking on his name using react.js

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

i want to be able to get the json info located on a localhost:5050 for a user by his id using axios get request and i want to do that by clicking his name from a previous get request i made to get all the info and display them. here is what i have so far

> my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import './employee.css';

function Employees() {
const [ employees, setEmployees ] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:5050/employees')
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            setEmployees(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);

const handleClick = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5050/employees/${employees.id}`).then((res) => {
        setEmployees(res.data);
    });
};

return (
    <div>
        <form>
            <h1>Employees</h1>
            <div className='employee-container'>
                <ul>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    {employees.map((employee) => (
                        <li key={employee.id} onClick={handleClick}>
                            {employee.name}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <label>Title</label>
                    {employees.map((employee) => <li key={employee.id}>{employee.title}</li>)}
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <label>Age</label>
                    {employees.map((employee) => <li key={employee.id}>{employee.age}</li>)}
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <label>Note</label>
                    {employees.map((employee) => <li key={employee.id}>{employee.note}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br />
            <Link to='/home' className='link-home'>
                Back Home
            </Link>
        </form>
    </div>
);
 }

  export default Employees;
```

> My JSON data:

[{"id":"1","name":"Ralph Bitar","title":"Manager","age":"20","note":""},{"id":"2","name":"Hussein Khatib","title":"developer","age":"20","note":"this is a note"},{"id":"3","name":"Samer Ghosn","title":"developer","age":"20","note":"this is another note"},{"id":"4","name":"Karim Hamadeh","title":"developer","age":"30","note":""}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass employee id in onclick method

```
  {employees.map((employee) => (
    <li key={employee.id} onClick={() => handleClick(employee.id)}>
        {employee.name}
    </li>
))}
```

then use employee id while doing api call

```
const handleClick = (employeeId) => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5050/employees/${employeeId}`).then((res) => {
        setEmployees(res.data);
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you it worked i didnt think of it that way still new to axios and fetching APIs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another state variable to hold the selected employee. You do not need to make another call to api `http://localhost:5050/employees/${employeeid}` as you are already fetching all the employees in your previous get request.

```
const [ selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployee ] = useState({});

...

<li key={employee.id} onClick={() => setSelectedEmployee(employee)}>
                            {employee.name}
                        </li>

...

<td>Id:{selectedEmployee.Id}</td>
<td>name:{selectedEmployee.name}</td>
<td>title:{selectedEmployee.title}</td>
```